# How to make an Amazon Route53 API call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, api, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create a subdomain in Amazon Route53 using an API call in Ruby. [Here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_CreateHostedZone.html) is the documentation for the API call I need to make.

First of all, I don't know how to make an API call in Ruby. I know I can use things like Net::HTTP, Open-URI or HTTParty (I don't know how to use any of them and tutorials are really rare).

Second of all, I don't understand how the API call should be made. Apparently I need to "send" an XML string with a bunch of headers (if I understand well, which I assume I don't). How do I generate that request?

Third of all, and finally, how do I "treat" the response.

What's the easiest way to do all those things in your opinion please?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about making Route 53 API calls here:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html?r=4900

Specifically in terms of Ruby, you may want to look into http://fog.io/1.2.0/index.html which supports AWS Route 53.